# data binding with an element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

WhY this notation does not work

```
const result1  = _model['dataarray[0]'];
```

`_model.dataarray` exists and it is an array with 2 elements

this "console.log(_model.dataarray[0])" works fines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `console.log(_model.dataarray[0])` works fine because `_model.dataarray[0]` is different from `_model['dataarray[0]']` which is incorrect, you shouldn't wrap the array index in the string.

Use the following syntax:

```
const result1  = _model['dataarray'][0];
```

Or like in the `console.log()`:

```
const result1  = _model.dataarray[0];
```

**Edit:**

To have a function that dynamically gets a value from an object whther this value is a `key` or not, this how could be your code:

```
getValue = function(_model, valueToFind){
    if(_model.hasOwnProperty(valueToFind)){
        return _model[valueToFind];
    }else if(valueToFind.indexOf("[")>0){
        let key  = valueToFind.substring(0, valueToFind.indexOf("["));
        let index = parseInt(valueToFind.charAt(parseInt(valueToFind.indexOf("["))+1));
        return _model[key][index];
    }else{
        console.log('Please input a valid key!!');
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
getValue = function(_model, valueToFind){
    if(_model.hasOwnProperty(valueToFind)){
        return _model[valueToFind];
    }else if(valueToFind.indexOf("[")>0){
        let key  = valueToFind.substring(0, valueToFind.indexOf("["));
        let index = parseInt(valueToFind.substring(valueToFind.indexOf("[")+1, valueToFind.indexOf("]")));
        console.log(index);
        return _model[key][index];
    }else{
        console.log('Please input a valid key!!');
    }
}

var _model = {dataarray: ["test1", "test2"]};

console.log(getValue(_model, "dataarray"));
console.log(getValue(_model, "dataarray[1]"));
console.log(getValue(_model, "property"));
```

**Note:**

This function takes only expressions like `dataarray[1]` or simple properties, you need to improve it to accept more complex expressions, I just wrote it to give you some hints on how to go with it.

Comment: if I use your method as recursive to build a full way. At end of fonction , i have buildField = 'dataArray'][0]['person']['firstname']. How I can use it with model ? I have try interpollation console.log(`resultat build ${_model+`${buildField}`}`);. But that does not work

Comment: The expression `'dataArray'][0]['person']['firstname']` is incorrect isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you wrapped the whole thing as a string and that is not the correct way of accessing a object properties. But only the key should be in string. Otherwise, the interpreter looks for a key called `dataarray[0]` which doesn't exist.

Correct syntax is

```
const result1  = _model['dataarray'][0];
```

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: How i can do to make it more generic. 
 _model['x'] x can be a string or an array

Comment: @Florence IMHO, one way is that you can check its type.

Comment: @Florence How could it be dynamic? can you show examples of how could be the keys in your OP?

Comment: @chsdk I would like to do a function like this getValue(_model, valueToFind){ return _model[valueToFind] I call this fontion getValue(dataModel,'dataArray[0]') => return the value for dataModel.dataArray[0] or getValue(dataModel,'name') => return the value for dataModel.name or getValue(dataModel,'dataArray[0].firstName')  retrun the value for dataModel.dataArray[0].firstName

Comment: @Florence I updated my answer with a simple solution but you should improve it for complex expressions.